# How to write simpler code on my scoring system in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm currently trying to write a simpler code where it can allow its users to pick a team then join a team event like a team sports for the different teams I've used a dictionary to store the different player names and the event they joined. Here's what I've done to for the dictionary

```
team1 = {"Team 1":["Martin","Kaz","Simba","Davis","Light"],"Score":[],"Event":[]}
team2 = {"Team 2":["John"],"Score":[],"Event":[]}
team3 = {"Team 3":["Kaz","Alex"],"Score":[],"Event":[]}
team4 = {"Team 4":["Jack","Pliskin"],"Score":[],"Event":[]}
```

I'm thinking of making a new def to let player pick the event they want their team to join in but the thing is I don't know how to make a more simpler looking code. I could use if/else statments to make it but that is going to take ages and quite inefficient. Here's my ideal output

```
What Team did you pick?: Team 1)
What sport would you like your team to join?: Basketball
team1["Event"].append(chosen_sport)
print(team1)
 {"Team 1":["Martin","Kaz","Simba","Davis","Light"],"Score":[],"Event":["Basketball]}
```

Any tips to make this happen while using simple looking code?

Comment: Where is the code you currently have?  And why aren't you asking this on Code Review?

Comment: "Any tips to make this happen while using simple looking code?" - this could be written several different ways. No one here wants to just write it for you. Give us your current code and we could make some recommendations, but in general if you're trying to optimize your code Code Review is a better place.

Comment: what is code review? I'm new to to coding and to this website so please excuse me

Comment: Check [Code Review on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you find yourself writing variables like `xxx1 = ...` / `xxx2 = ...` / `xxx3 = ...`, that can almost always be handled better as a list.

```
teams = [
    {"Team":["Martin","Kaz","Simba","Davis","Light"],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
    {"Team":["John"],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
    {"Team":["Kaz","Alex"],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
    {"Team":["Jack","Pliskin"],"Score":[],"Event":[]}
]
```

Now you can refer to `teams[0]` to get Team 1.  Maybe you need a "Name" in there as well.  Or, in your case, since you already have a key, you could just make one big dict:

```
teams = {
    "Team 1":{"Team":["Martin","Kaz","Simba","Davis","Light"],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
    "Team 2":{"Team":["John"],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
    "Team 3":{"Team":["Kaz","Alex"],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
    "Team 4":{"Team":["Jack","Pliskin"],"Score":[],"Event":[]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use 4 different dicts? I do not know the reason.

I think this kind of dict would be better:

```
teamsdata = {1:{'name':'team 1','members':['Martin','Kaz'],'score':[],'event':[]},
             2:{'name':'team 2','members':['John'],'score':[],'event':[]}
             }
```

In this way, you can solve it with:

```
try:
    str_team = input('What Team did you pick?')
    team = int(str_team)
except ValueError as e:
    print(f'{str_team} is not a valid team.')
    raise

chosen_sport = input('What sport would you like your team to join?')

teamsdata[team]['event'].append(chosen_sport)

print(teamsdata[team])
```